# How would I compile a compiler without a compiler?

Tags: macos

I am attempting to get some software to compile on Mac OS X 10.0 (Cheetah). The code is written in C, so I thought I could simply use GCC. However, all the GCC pre-compiled binaries I could find online were executable formats macOS did not recognize. However, Mach-O binaries appear to work. So, how can I get a compiler for this platform without a compiler?

Comment: xcode can compile C... and you install gcc like any other software on OS X: using home`brew` or mac`ports`.

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X Cheetah, so nothing really existed at this time.

Comment: um, xcode existed definitely. what do you think apple gave companies that were supposed to port software to OS X?

Comment: Cheetah was released in 2001, Xcode released in 2003. I have not been able to find a version that works with cheetah

Comment: Uff. so best guess is asking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darling_(software) how they produce Mach-O binaries.

Comment: What does that have to do with this?

Comment: They have an environment in which they can build Mach-O binaries for OS X.

Comment: This question does not make sense. Change "compile" to "drive" and "compiler" to "car", and you have "How can I DRIVE a CAR without a CAR?" Does that make any sense, either? Many users here will not bother reading this question for that reason. Please clarify your question (by editing it), and you will likely have a lot more users reading it and trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Mac OS X 10.0, you’d be best off getting the corresponding Developer Tools CD (March 2001).

Comment: Just check it out, and it seems like it either doesn't support C99 or just doesn't work in some cases, but I feel like this is the closest I can get, so thanks!